# SplitView how to change the min-width before split

Tags: jquery-mobile, uisplitview

SplitView works well with jQuery Mobile. But apparently adapted to iPad.
Actually, I'm working on a 7 inch tab and I would like the splitview to display starting about 300px.
I tried to change the min-width in the "splitview.css" file but it does not seem to work.
Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

search in teh splitview.js for

```
$menu.removeClass('panel-popover')
                        .addClass('ui-panel-left')
                        .css({'width':'25%', 'min-width':'250px', 'display':''});
```

u can change the width and min-width there. hope that helps. :)

Comment: Think I will go back to what I was looking for. Since it doesn't change anything for me